# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config/default_warehouse_mongo_db'

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI all! I'm trying create a moveit package for my own robot following the tutorial Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot. When I finished the second part Update Configuration Files I tested the configuation.However, there was something wrong. When I start the planning _and_execution.launch, there was something output like this:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config/default_warehouse_mongo_db'

[mongo_wrapper_ros_shantengfei_PC_9122_1384786663048058499-7] process has died [pid 9194, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/warehouse_ros/mongo_wrapper_ros.py __name:=mongo_wrapper_ros_shantengfei_PC_9122_1384786663048058499 __log:=/home/shantengfei/.ros/log/e378d02c-b477-11e7-9896-7085c22fcebd/mongo_wrapper_ros_shantengfei_PC_9122_1384786663048058499-7.log].
log file: /home/shantengfei/.ros/log/e378d02c-b477-11e7-9896-7085c22fcebd/mongo_wrapper_ros_shantengfei_PC_9122_1384786663048058499-7*.log
```

I checked the ros package **jaka_ur_moveit_config** and there are just two folders: **launch** and **config**. In the **launch** folder, there is a **default_warehouse_db.launch**  file which was generated when I set up the moveit assistant:

```
<launch>

  <arg name="reset" default="false"/>
  <!-- If not specified, we'll use a default database location -->
  <arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" default="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" />

  <!-- Launch the warehouse with the configured database location -->
  <include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/launch/warehouse.launch">
    <arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" value="$(arg moveit_warehouse_database_path)" />
  </include>



 <!-- If we want to reset the database, run this node -->
  <node if="$(arg reset)" name="$(anon moveit_default_db_reset)" type="moveit_init_demo_warehouse" pkg="moveit_ros_warehouse" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

and here is the moveit_planning_execution.launch

```
<launch>

  <arg name="sim" default="true" />
  <arg name="robot_ip" unless="$(arg sim)" />

  <include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch" >
    <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true" />
  </include>

  <group if="$(arg sim)">
    <include file="$(find industrial_robot_simulator)/launch/robot_interface_simulator.launch" />
  </group>

  <group unless="$(arg sim)">
    <include file="$(find [robot_interface_pkg])/launch/robot_interface.launch" >
      <arg name="robot_ip" value="$(arg robot_ip)"/>
    </include>
  </group>

  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

  <include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
    <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true" />
  </include>

  <include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
    <arg name="config" value="true"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/launch/default_warehouse_db.launch" />

</launch>
```

As can be seen, `<arg name="moveit_warehouse_database_path" default="$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db" />`. But I didn't find the `default_warehouse_mongo_db`.Could  someone please give a method to solve the problem? Thanks.
PS: Here is the output of   `ls -al /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config`

```
    drwxr-xr-x 4 root        root        4096 10月 16 10:00 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 shantengfei shantengfei 4096 10月 18 22:51 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root         310 10月 16 10:00 CMakeLists.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root        4096 10月 23 15:33 config
drwxr-xr-x 2 root        root        4096 10月 17 16:32 launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root        1069 10月 16 10:00 package.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root        root         284 10月 16 10:00 .setup_assistant
```

and the output of `ls -al /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config/launch`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 10月 17 16:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 10月 16 10:00 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   715 10月 16 10:00 default_warehouse_db.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2521 10月 16 10:00 demo.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   370 10月 16 10:00 fake_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   299 10月 17 16:32 jakaUr_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20 10月 16 10:00 jakaUr_moveit_sensor_manager.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   629 10月 16 10:00 joystick_control.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3418 10月 16 10:00 move_group.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1051 10月 17 15:07 moveit_planning_execution.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   968 10月 17 15:05 moveit_planning_execution.launch~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19020 10月 16 10:00 moveit.rviz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   672 10月 16 10:00 moveit_rviz.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   966 10月 16 10:00 ompl_planning_pipeline.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1208 10月 16 10:00 planning_context.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   335 10月 16 10:00 planning_pipeline.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   910 10月 16 10:00 run_benchmark_ompl.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   647 10月 16 10:00 sensor_manager.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   540 10月 16 10:00 setup_assistant.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1329 10月 16 10:00 trajectory_execution.launch.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   523 10月 16 10:00 warehouse.launch
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   592 10月 16 10:00 warehouse_settings.launch.xml
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273819/oserror:-%5Berrno-13%5D-permission-denied:-%27/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config/default_warehouse_mongo_db%27/) by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2017-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-23**:
Your launch file is looking for `$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/default_warehouse_mongo_db"` and you said that there is a `config` folder.

If your `default_warehouse_mongo_db` is in the `config` folder, then your `launch` should be `$(find jaka_ur_moveit_config)/config/default_warehouse_mongo_db"`

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-23**:
What is the output of `find . -name default_warehouse_mongo_db` after run `roscd jaka_ur_moveit_config` ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
The `default_warehouse_mongo_db` is created if it doesn't exist on first run of a MoveIt config with the `db` enabled. So that it doesn't exist (yet) is expected.

@tengfei: did you ever run anything as a different user (ie: `root`?) in your workspace? That could lead to these sort of issues.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Also: please edit your question to include your `moveit_planning_execution.launch` file.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-23**:
Hi Ruben, thanks for your reply.I didn't found the default_warehouse_mongo_db in the **config** folder and I tried the `find . -name default_warehouse_mongo_db after run roscd jaka_ur_moveit_config` and there was nothing output.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-23**:
Hi gvdhoorn thanks for your reply every time! Maybe I uese sudo, I forgot it. So how to resolve this problem? I even don't know what the default_warehouse_mongo_db's role in this project.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Please add the full output of `ls -al /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config` to your question text.

If (and only if) permissions are the problem, we can reset them.

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-23**:
gvdhoorn, I have add the ouput of the `ls -al /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config`. Please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From:

> When I start the `planning _and_execution.launch`, there was something output like this:
>
> ```
> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config/default_warehouse_mongo_db'
> [..]
> ```

and

> Here is the output of   `ls -al /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config`
>
> ```
> drwxr-xr-x 4 root        root        4096 10月 16 10:00 .
> [..]
> ```

it would appear you've most likely either changed the permissions on these folders and made them owned by `root`, or have run the MoveIt Setup Assistant as `root` (with `sudo` perhaps).

If you now try to start `demo.launch` or `moveit_planning_execution.launch`, the Mongo DB will try to create the necessary files in a directory owned by `root`. As your regular user (`shantengfei`) does not have permissions to do that, you receive a `OSError: Permission denied`.

Easiest is most likely to change the owner of the affected folders and files. For that, try:

```
chown -R shantengfei: /home/shantengfei/catkin_ws/src/jaka_ur_moveit_config
```

Note the semicolon (`:`) and I've assumed that your username is `shantengfei`. If it isn't, please use the correct username.

And it's probably not necessary, but just in case: remove the `devel` and `build` folders from your workspace and build it again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
And a suggestion: model your `moveit_planning_execution.launch` after those in `fanuc`.

Note the highlighted lines [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/be50b86561e620bc86680d9dd84ae0d9eae022c6/fanuc_lrmate200ic5h_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch#L18-L21) ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
.. and [here](https://github.com/ros-industrial/fanuc/blob/be50b86561e620bc86680d9dd84ae0d9eae022c6/fanuc_lrmate200ic5h_moveit_config/launch/moveit_planning_execution.launch#L54-L57).

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-23**:
Thanks for your help. Now it works without the error! And I'm sorry that I cannot understand your suggestions well? Should I model the two highlight parts and change the path then put it into my launch file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-23**:
Use the file I linked as a template and replace all `fanuc` references with your own robot/packages. The `moveit_planning_execution.launch` I linked you to is a bit more up-to-date than the one in the tutorial you followed.

So it will not create a db, unless it has been requested fi.